# Relationship between $\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$

Tags: expected-value

Is  $\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$ equivalent with $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$?

The definition of $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^+)-\mathbb{E}(X^-)<\infty$. And this is equivalent with $\mathbb{E}|X| = \mathbb{E}(X^+)+\mathbb{E}(X^-)<\infty$. Right?

Comment: It is true that $E(X)<\infty$ iff $E|X|<\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rigorously (measure-wise), the expectation of a random variable $\mathbb E[X]$ can **only** be considered if the expectation of the absolute value $\mathbb E[|X|]$ is finite, otherwise **the former is not defined**, as in the Cauchy case. (See the answers to this earlier question:
[What makes the mean of some distributions undefined?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/232975/7224).)

Answer (score 0):

This gets definitional, but suppose $Z$ is a standard Cauchy random variable and $X= -|Z|$, so $X\leq 0$ and $$\lim_{c\to-\infty} E[X\{X> c\}]=-\infty.$$
I would typically say $E[X]<\infty$ but not $E[|X|]< \infty$. $E[X]$ is signed; the sign matters.

Along similar lines, I would say that $E[Z]<\infty$ is undefined but $E[|Z|]<\infty$ is false.

Comment: Is $E(Z)<\infty$?

Comment: I wrote that I thought it was undefined whether that was the case or not.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your point, Thomas. The integral$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,\text dx$$does not exist.

Comment: Yes, exactly. E[Z] doesn't exist, so  $E[Z]<\infty$ doesn't even have a true/false value, whereas $E[|Z|]<\infty$ is straightforwardly false.